# Use storcli to get / set spare drive

Tags: raid, lsi, storcli

I have an LSI controller with a R10 array consisting of 4 drives + 1 spare.  Storcli reports:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                  Sp Type
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0     3 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:1     5 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:2     6 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:3     7 Onln   0 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
252:4     4 UGood  - 5.457 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD6002FRYZ-01WD5B1 U  -
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Details of slt 4 shows:

```
Drive /c0/e252/s4 Policies/Settings :
===================================
Enclosure position = 1
Connected Port Number = 4(path0)
Sequence Number = 3
Commissioned Spare = No
Emergency Spare = No
```

I would like to make drive 4 a global hot spare.  Another post suggested using the command:

```
storcli /c0/e252/s4 add hotsparedrive
```

But how does that relate to "Commissioned Spare" vs "Emergency Spare" above.  I just want this disk to be a spare in case any drive fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Emergency Spare` is a "last resort" spare when the controller uses a `UGood` drive or an otherwise incompatible global hot spare to rebuild the failed array. On some controller model this also activate the alarm sound.

`Commissioned Spare` simply indicates if the disk is in active use as normal or emergency hotspare (ie: if another disk failed and this one took its place).